# Como acceder desde afuera al valor de una variable que esta en el ambito de una funcion de callback en NODE

Tags: nodejs, backend, callback

Los saludo amigos de la gran famila stackoverflow, mi pregunta es la siguiente segun el codigo de abajo en NODE.JS como hago para acceder al valor de la variable mensaje de manera de enviar este mensaje con res.send a mi frontend, como podras ver el res.send lo saque fuera del for ya que si coloco el res.send dentro de la funcion de callback del INSERT me daria error por intentar enviar muchas respuestas a mi cliente debido al for, es por ello que saque el res.send fuera del for; pero una vez que el for culmina  no se como acceder al valor de la variable mensaje del callback del INSERT desde afuera y poder enviarlo a mi frontend por medio de res.send(mensaje). Alguna idea  ? Gracias....

```
var mensaje

     req.getConnection((err, conn) => {

         for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
       
               let name = req.files[i].originalname

               var post  = {nombreOriginal: name};
       
               conn.query('INSERT INTO imagenes set ?', post, (err,rows) => {
                 if (err){mensaje=err}
                 else{mensaje='Se guardaron las imagenes'}
               })
         }              
         res.send(mensaje)  
     }
```